# Optional choosing functions and their arguments by user

Tags: python, function, user-controls

I ran into a challenge and I decided to ask it here.
Look I use the following code is for the explanation below it:

```
x=y=z=2
def function1(x):
   return 2+x
def function2(y):
   return 4+y
def function3(z):
   return 6 +z 
use_1 = input("Type T to use 1 ")
use_2 = input("Type T to use 2 ")
use_3 = input("Type T to use 3 ")
h=(use_1=='T')*function1(x)+(use_2=='T')*function2(y)+(use_3=='T')*function3(z)
print(h)
```

**** explanation:
this code for this reason that user decide to use which one of those functions. The user may want to use, 1 and 3 or 2 and 3 or 1 and 2 or even 1 or 2 or 3. It is possible by choosing `T`.

Now I have a big challenge:
I am writting the following code just for one question. We can see that if funcrion `1` is chosen by the user so its arguments are used in the code but if user does not choose function `3` its argument which are `e` and `q` should be removed in the rest of the code " every where that `e` exists". We do it manually, by removing and modifying the code.
Is there any way when user chooses `1` and does not choose other function just `a` and `q`  are in the code?
I mean all `e`, `c` are removed automatically.

I hope to make good understanding of my opinion.

```
    ao = np.zeros((N,))
    ao[0] = 0.3         
    an = np.zeros((N,))

    q0o = np.zeros((N,))
    qo[0] = 0.3         
    q0n = np.zeros((N,))

    c0o = np.zeros((N,))
    c0o[0] = 69           
    c0n = np.zeros((N,))

    eo = np.zeros((N,))
    eo[0] = 0.1       
    en = np.zeros((N,))
    temp = 1e10 
    def 1(a,q):
            return a+q**2
    def 2(c,q):
            return c/sqrt(q)
    def 3(e,q):
            return q-e
    def TOTAL(a, c, e, q)  :
                      total =  1(a,q) + 2(c,q) + 3(e,q)
                      return total

    highest=0
    with open('outputs/poly.txt', 'w') as f:
            for i in range (1,N):
                num = 0
                R = np.random.uniform(0,1)    
                while True:
                    num += 1
                    an[i] = ao[i-1] + 0.001 * np.random.normal()
                    c0n[i] = c0o[i-1] + 0.01 * np.random.normal()
                    e0n[i] = e0o[i-1] + 0.01 * np.random.normal()

                    L = np.exp(-0.5 * (TOTAL(an[i], c0n[i], e0n[i], qn[i]) - TOTAL(ao[i-1], c0o[i-1], e0o[i-1], qo[i-1])))
                    LL=min(1,max(L,0))

                    if LL>R:          
                        ao[i]= an[i]
                        c0o[i] = c0n[i]
                        e0o[i] = e0n[i]
                        qo[i] = qn[i]
                        chi = TOTAL(ao[i], c0o[i], e0o[i], qo[i])
                    else:           
                        ao[i]= ao[i-1]
                        c0o[i] = co[i-1]
                        e0o[i] = e0o[i-1]
                        qo[i] = qo[i-1]
                        chi = TOTAL(ao[i], c0o[i], e0o[i], qo[i])


                    if (ao[i]>0 and c0o[i]>0 and e0o[i]>0)  or num>100:               
                        highest = max(num, highest)
                        break

                f.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\n".format(round(chi,5),'  ',round(c0o[i],5),'  ',round(qo[i],5)))
```

Comment: So you actually want to remove the declaration of the variable inside the code if the function is not invoked? I don't think this is possible, since the result is only known at runtime.

Comment: BTW please show desired output

Comment: @AlexanderPane I saw it in CosmoMC code, written in FORTRAN. Also We can say that optional function and optional arguments. Python can ask us which functions? and the, which arguments? then according to our choice it uses functions and arguments.